# Error Parsing Data java.lang.NullPointerExceptionnull

Tags: php, android, json

I have been able to use the PHP code below for other activity and it works fine, but for this particular activity its giving me a null pointer exception.

This is my code

```
    public void getData(List<? extends NameValuePair> namevalue) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String result = "";
             InputStream isr = null;
             try
             {
             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/view.php");
             httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(namevalue));
             HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
             HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
             isr = entity.getContent();
             }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
             e2.setText("Couldnt connect to database");
             }
             //convert response to string

             try
             {
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
             String line = null;
             while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
             sb.append(line + "\n");
             }
             isr.close();

             result=sb.toString();

             }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
             }
             try
                {  String usn=null;
                 String g=null  ;
                 String dob=null;
                 String yop=null;
                 String email=null;
                 String phone = null;
                 String tenyop = null;
                 String tenp=null;
                 String twelyop=null;
                 String twelp=null;
                 String dipyop=null;
                 String dipp=null;
                 String branch=null;
                 String s1=null;
                 String s2=null;
                 String s3=null;
                 String s4=null;
                 String s5=null;
                 String s6=null;
                 String s7=null;
                 String s8=null;
                 String fa=null;
                 String back=null;
                 String aggre=null;


                 JSONArray jArray =  new JSONArray(result);
                 for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++)
                 {
                 JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                 usn = " "+json.getString("usn")+"\n";
                 g= " "+json.getString("gender")+"\n";
                 yop=" "+json.getString("yop")+"\n";
                 dob = dob + " "+json.getString("dob")+"\n";
                 email=" "+json.getString("email")+"\n";
                 phone=" "+json.getString("phone_no")+"\n";
                 tenyop =" "+json.getString("tenyop")+"\n";
                 tenp= " "+json.getString("tenperc")+"\n";
                 twelyop=" "+json.getString("twelveyop")+"\n";
                 twelp = " "+json.getString("twelveperc")+"\n";
                 dipyop= " "+json.getString("dipyop")+"\n";
                 dipp= " "+json.getString("dipperc")+"\n";
                 branch= " "+json.getString("branch")+"\n";
                 s1= " "+json.getString("sem1")+"\n";
                 s2=  " "+json.getString("sem2")+"\n";
                 s3=  " "+json.getString("sem3")+"\n";
                 s4=  " "+json.getString("sem4")+"\n";
                 s5=  " "+json.getString("sem5")+"\n";
                 s6=  " "+json.getString("sem6")+"\n";
                 s7=  " "+json.getString("sem7")+"\n";
                 s8=  " "+json.getString("sem8")+"\n";
                 fa=  " "+json.getString("fa")+"\n";
                 back= " "+json.getString("back")+"\n";
                 //aggre=" "+json.getString("aggregate")+"\n";
                }

                 e2.setText(dob);

                 e3.setText(phone);
                 e4.setText(tenyop);
                 e5.setText(tenp);
                 e6.setText(twelyop);
                 e7.setText(twelp);
                 e8.setText(dipyop);
                 e9.setText(dipp);
                 sem1.setText(s1);
                 sem2.setText(s2);
                 sem3.setText(s3);
                 sem4.setText(s4);
                 sem5.setText(s5);
                 sem6.setText(s6);
                 sem7.setText(s7);
                 sem8.setText(s8);
                 e10.setText(fa);
                 e11.setText(back);
                }
   catch (Exception e) 
   {
     Log.e("log_tag1", "Error Parsing Data "+e.toString());
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
     }
```

}

My php code is

```
<?php
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if(!$con)
        die('could not connect: ' .mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("portal",$con);
    $usn=$_POST['usn'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM LOGIN where usn='$usn'");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $output[]=$row;
    }
    echo(json_encode($output));
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

And below is the exception:

```
04-07 11:35:39.573: E/log_tag1(1058): Error Parsing Data java.lang.NullPointerException
04-07 11:35:39.603: W/System.err(1058): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-07 11:35:39.603: W/System.err(1058):     at com.example.app.Userpage.getData(Userpage.java:488)
04-07 11:35:39.613: W/System.err(1058):     at com.example.app.Userpage.onCreate(Userpage.java:92)
04-07 11:35:39.613: W/System.err(1058):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-07 11:35:39.613: W/System.err(1058):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-07 11:35:39.613: W/System.err(1058):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-07 11:35:39.613: W/System.err(1058):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-07 11:35:39.613: W/System.err(1058):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-07 11:35:39.613: W/System.err(1058):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-07 11:35:39.613: W/System.err(1058):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-07 11:35:39.613: W/System.err(1058):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-07 11:35:39.613: W/System.err(1058):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-07 11:35:39.623: W/System.err(1058):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-07 11:35:39.623: W/System.err(1058):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-07 11:35:39.623: W/System.err(1058):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-07 11:35:39.623: W/System.err(1058):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-07 11:35:39.623: W/System.err(1058):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please help me. This is important for my project

Comment: format your code and post the stacktrace

Comment: Where's the null pointexception? Please post your logcat.

Comment: if your HTTP client code block throws an error it will just be logged, swallowed and then move on down to reading from the null ISR variable. Is that where you're NullPointerException is coming from?

Comment: post your log cat please

Comment: I am sorry i cannot post images but ill add the logcat error here. Pleasee do check


04-07 11:35:39.573: E/log_tag1(1058): Error Parsing Data java.lang.NullPointerException
04-07 11:35:39.603: W/System.err(1058): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-07 11:35:39.603: W/System.err(1058):  at com.example.app.Userpage.getData(Userpage.java:488)
04-07 11:35:39.613: W/System.err(1058):  at com.example.app.Userpage.onCreate(Userpage.java:92)

Comment: You don't send parameter $_POST['usn']. Where is setting usn to namevalue ?

Comment: The updation to database is working fine and i have note posted that code. i have added the usn in namevalue pair, What is need is, if there are values already present for a particular they should be retrieved and displayed. This part is giving me error. i hope you understand

Comment: List<NameValuePair> namevalue= new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
         namevalue.add(new BasicNameValuePair("usn",msg));
   getData(namevalue);

I have sent the usn in name value pair. I just forgot to add the code. sorry. here msg is the usn